# Accumulation Point and Continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Below is the Definition of Continuity.

Let $(M, d), (N, ρ)$ be the metric spaces, $ A \subset M $ and $ f: A \to  
 N $ be a given map.

Then f is continuous at $x_0 \in A$ if either $x_0 \notin acc(A)$ or  $  \lim\limits_{x \to x_0}f(x) = f({x_0})$

---

Question : How one could understand the condition $x_0 \notin acc(A)$ could be a definition of continuity?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_0 \notin acc(A)$. Then there is a neighborhood $N$ of $x_0$ such that

(*)   $(N \setminus \{x_0\}) \cap A= \emptyset$.

Now let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $A$ with $x_n \to x_0$. From (*) we get that there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $x_n=x_0$ for $n>N$.

It follows that $f(x_n)=f(x_0)$ for $n > N$, hence

$f(x_n) \to f(x_0)$.

This shows that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Comment: What guarantees that we can choose sequence $(x_n)$ in $A$ with $x_n \to x_0$?

Comment: We have $x_0 \in A$. A trivial example is $x_n=x_0$ for all $n$.